# How to define a mixed model in R. Repeated measures or time-series ? Which effect should be random?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, random-effects-model

Hello to the CrossValidated community. I could use some help.

I am struggling with the analysis of an experiment, specifically with deciding and defining in code the structure of a mixed model for analysing it.

The experimental design is as follows:

We wanted to see if there are any differences on the growth of lesions caused by different combinations of pathogens (**Treatment** in the data).

To investigate this we used detached leaves and inoculated them with said Treatments. Each leaf was inoculated in two spots which were averaged to give us the **Area** of each lesion. Measurements were done per day for all leaves in the experiment, for days 4-9 after the inoculation (**Day** in the data below).

Two difference cultivars of potato plants were used in the experiment (**Cultivar** in the data).

Leaves were arranged in boxes (**Box** in the data) for a complete randomized block design. Each box contained 7 leaves of each cultivar, each leaf inoculated with one of the **Treatment**, so a total of 14 leaves in each box.

**LeafID** is a unique identifier for each of leaves in the experiment.

My understanding is that **Box**, **Cultivar**, **Treatment** and **Day** are crossed factors. **LeafID** is crossed with **Day** and **Box** and nested within **Treatment** and **Cultivar**. I am mentioning this to check my understanding of the experimental design and furthermore to understand if it's important for defining the model. I seem to remember reading that lmer accounts for nested or crossed designs internally but can't quote a source unfortunately.

Here is a pick at my data structure in R, **Day** and **Area** are coded as *double*, all other variables are coded as *factors*

```
Box Cultivar Treatment  Day  LeafID Area
1   Arsenal  Control    4    121    0.0000000
1   Arsenal  Control    5    121    0.0000000
1   Arsenal  Control    6    121    0.0000000
1   Arsenal  Control    7    121    0.0000000
1   Arsenal  Control    8    121    0.0000000
1   Arsenal  Control    9    121    0.0000000
1   Arsenal  A.solani   4    21     0.1745344
1   Arsenal  A.solani   5    21     0.3062256
1   Arsenal  A.solani   6    21     0.3721086
1   Arsenal  A.solani   7    21     0.4217482
....
```

My understanding is that this can be analysed as either a repeated measures or a time-series design, and the choice really depends on the research question. I chose to look at this as a repeated measures design, mostly because it's easier for me to grasp the concepts and statistics involved. I am more than happy to hear differing opinions of course!

I tried to fit my model the same way Crawley does in the R Book (p,695, "*Mixed-effects models with temporal pseudoreplication*")

Initially we came up with the following model:

```
m0.full <- lme(data=DLA2, Area ~ Treatment * Cultivar * Day  ,
random = ~Day | LeafID, na.action = na.exclude ,method = "ML")
```

The difference from what Crawley does is that our model has extra fixed effects and their interactions **Treatment * Cultivar * Day** and we are using *Day* and its interaction as we care about the progress over time and how this affects our growth.

What I am struggling with is deciding if **Cultivar** should be a fixed or random effect and if including **Day** in the fixed effects also gives the wrong interpretation.

I've spent countless hours going through mixed model tutorials and I know that going for a very complex model is not the way to go. I guess the most confusing part is deciding what to have as fixed and random. I've seen some people suggesting you can use a factor in both fixed and random parts of the model but i have trouble grasping the concept.

I would be happy to share the entire dataset if that helps, any suggestions of the best way to do this would be welcome.

I am looking forward for some suggestions on how to handle my analysis and what could be improved.

I would be happy using either lme or lmer.

Thank you all for your time!

**EDIT: I added a plot of my data for each different Treatment*Cultivar combination. Each panel shows the full replicates corresponding to the combination**

[image: Daily growth in lesion radius of each Treatment*Cultivar combination]

**UPDATE**

I came up with these two models, mod.rep takes into account the repeated measures of the Day variable, while mod.time uses a time-series approach as used by Crawley(The R Book). I also accounted for heteroscedasticity using the varIdent function.

Are those models correct ?

```
mod.rep <- lme(data=DLA2, Radius ~ Treatment * Cultivar, random = ~ 
Day|LeafID, na.action = na.omit ,method = "ML", weights = 
varIdent(form=~1|Treatment))

mod.time <- lme(data=DLA2, Radius ~  Day * Treatment * Cultivar, random = 
~1|LeafID, na.action = na.exclude ,method = "ML", weights = 
varIdent(form=~1|Treatment))
```

I still have some trouble translating the random effects formulas into words...

Comment: Does this Q&A help you https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-and-mixed-effect-mode/151800#151800

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I have read it in the past and it does not help much with my particular questions regarding my dataset (like how to define the models and deal with the Day variable)

Comment: It seems to me that Cultivar, having only two levels and representing the totality of cultivars to which you might generalise, is fixed.

Comment: If you fit a random slope model (for Day) i would have thought you also wanted to have it in your model as a fixed effect. Similarly if you have a random intercept model you usually have the intercept in the model too (which by default you will have I think).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regarding the cultivar as a fixed effect, I would accept this without question if my main questions was how Cultivar affects the lesion growth together with the treatment.

Comment: In my case, I use 2 different Cultivars to get information on the effect of the Cultivar might have on the Treatment but not directly caring about it. And since the 2 cultivars are drawn from a very diverse choice of many different cultivars, let me quote Crawley :

**Random effects have factor levels that are drawn from a large (potentially very large) population in which
the individuals differ in many ways, but we do not know exactly how or why they differ.**

Comment: It is philosophically reasonable but not practical to treat a two-level factor as random (when using modern mixed models): see last paragraph of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-and-mixed-effect-mode/155056#155056

Comment: That was a good read. So many people are having conflicting opinions that seems selecting something as random is a matter of preference or convenience sometimes.

Comment: So I have come up with two models, but I need some help understanding what they actually mean, one is: `lme.dla2 <- lme(data=dla2015, Radius ~ Species * Cultivar , random = ~Day|Isolate/Cultivar, method="ML", weights = varIdent(form=~1|Isolate), control=list(msMaxIter=100,opt  = "optim",msVerbose=TRUE))`

And the other is :`lme.dla1 <- lme(data=dla2015, Radius ~ Species * Cultivar , random = ~Day|LeafID, method="ML", weights = varIdent(form=~1|Isolate), control=list(msMaxIter=100,opt  = "optim",msVerbose=TRUE))`

lme.dla1 is more clear to me, as I am just replicating what Crawley does.

Answer (score 1):

In section 1.5 of Pinheiro and Bates (2000) *Mixed Effects Models in S and S-Plus*, you can find the reference for analyzing nested factors with the nlme package, which is related to lmer. The syntax for defining the nested factors can also be found in the same passage. The book is written about S, but these functions mostly work in R without problems.

For example to introduce a free intercept for a nested factor you could write `random = ~1|Box/LeafID` (This is just an example, I don't say that this is relevant to the specific experiment.) You can then gradually introduce slopes in the random effects, like `update(your_model, random = ~Treatment|Box/LeafID)`, so that to get random effects for the slope of Treatment as well, and compare model fit. (You can similarly build up your way to the triple interaction term in the fixed effects.)

Comment: So how does the use of `random=~Day|LeafID` account for the repeated measure pseudoreplication in my first model ? I don't quite get the syntax (this is what Crawley does...)

Comment: It is interpreted as a different slope ($b_{day,i}$ for each leaf. (Having in mind that Y = ... random = ~1|Box means 'assume a different mean for each Box'. https://github.com/giswqs/Learning-R/blob/master/Discovering-Statistics-Using-R/Scripts/Chapter%2013%20DSUR%20GLM4.R -- see lines 105-6 for using an lme as repeated measures. I believe it is something in the lines of `random = ~1|Box/Day` -- different intercept for each Box and each Day, because Box is the entity and Day the repeated measure.

Comment: I am not taking Box into account at all. LeafID is just the identity of each leaf. Day is where pseudoreplication occurs, unless I try and analyse as a time series. So I am assuming you mean `random = ~1|LeafID/Day` ?

Comment: If your theoretical entity is the Leaf then yes.

Comment: So is `random = ~Day|LeafID` the same as `random = ~1|LeafID/Day` ?

Comment: The first is a different (intercept and (slope for each day) for each Leaf), the latter is a different (intercept (for each day within each leaf))  plus a different (intercept for each leaf). There are $n*(m + 1)$ random effect parameters to be estimated in the former and $mn + n$ in the latter, where $n$ the number of leaves and $m$ the number of days. You can see the difference if you fit both models and then call `ranef(model1)` and `ranef(model2)` to see the difference.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank you, the latter does not even converge. Probably because LeafID is the smallest possible unit and just an ID really for each of the measured leaves

Comment: I would give a chance to Box in LeafID's stead though. In this case you treat Leaves as repeated measures of Boxes. That leaves you with substantially less parameters to estimate, and the information of individual leaves will be averaged in each Box's intercepts and Day slopes. I have an intuition that this approach fits with the randomized block design. Think of the original agricultural experiments by Fisher; the entities of interest were the plots receiving the treatment, not each individual plant in the plot.

Comment: So how would you write the model ? If I try to use Box instead of LeafID in mod.rep, my model does not converge.
But still isn't the entity of interest the leaf here ? remember, each box has 14 leaves, 7 for each cultivar, and each one has 1 of 7 treatments applied to it

Comment: Perhaps I did not understand your block design before. Since you look for difference in growth you may want to examine the Day slope across Treatments, so perhaps compare model with `random = ~1|LeafID/Treatment` to model with `random = ~Day|LeafID/Treatment`. Significant `anova()` between the models would then mean different growth across Treatments. Perhaps also start off with `Area~1` in the formula, then start adding main effect and interaction terms one by one.

Comment: So if I want to compare Day slope (and intercept?) across treatments wouldn't the structure be `random = ~Day|Treatment` ? What does adding LeafID as you indicated achieve ?

Comment: It takes account of the fact that the measures come from the same individuals over time. If you didn't want that I think you could just look at the  interaction term Cultivar * Treatment.

Comment: I do care for taking into account that measurements come from the same individuals. As you suggested I tried `random = ~Day|LeafID/Treatment` and `random = ~1|LeafID/Treatment`.
With the first option the model does not converge. I would have to do it like this
`mod.timeAR <-  lme(data=DLA2, Radius ~ Day * Treatment *  Cultivar, random = ~0 +  Day|LeafID/Treatment, ,na.action=na.omit, weight=varIdent(form=~1|Treatment), method="ML", correlation = corARMA(q=2, form=~Day))`